# Call Go string-return function from Python

Tags: python, go, c-strings

I try to call this

```
// cryptography.go
func getDecryptedMessage(message string, d int, prime1 int, prime2 int) *C.char {
///
//do something
/////
return C.CString("hello from go")
}

//app.py

lib = cdll.LoadLibrary("./cryptography.so")

class go_string(Structure):
 _fields_ = [
 ("p", c_char_p),
 ("n", c_longlong)]

lib.getDecryptedMessage.restype = c_char_p
b = go_string(c_char_p(decryptedMsg), len(decryptedMsg))
print (lib.getDecryptedMessage(b, c.d,c.prime1, c.prime2))
```

It will print: b'hello from go'.
The result should be: hello from go

I build it with

```
go build -buildmode=c-shared -o cryptography.so cryptography.go
```

Anyone can help me?
Edit : I think it must be something wrong with

```
lib.getDecryptedMessage.restype = c_char_p
```

Here is a smaller version:

```
//app.py
from flask import Flask, jsonify
from flask import abort
from flask import make_response
from flask import request
from flask_cors import CORS
from ctypes import *
import ctypes

lib = cdll.LoadLibrary("./a.so")
lib.getMessage.restype = c_char_p
print(lib.getMessage())

//a.go
package main
import "C"

//export getMessage
func getMessage() *C.char {
    return C.CString("hello from go")
}
```

It will return: b'hello from go'

Comment: does this help https://gist.github.com/helinwang/4f287a52efa4ab75424c01c65d77d939 ?

Comment: That exactly what I'm doing. But i get different output

Comment: the first comment shows a much simpler version which sems to work almost out of the box

Comment: I tried. But cannot make it work. It returns weird character for me

Comment: What is `decryptedMsg`? Can you post the whole or at least the relevant source code?

Comment: @EndreSimo You can look at compact version at the end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It will print: `b'hello from go'`.

That's completely normal.  C strings have a byte based type.

In Python 2, the `bytes` and `str` types are the same, so Py2k apps see C strings as strings.  In Python 3, the `bytes` type is different from the `str` type.  To convert a `bytes` to a `str`, you must decode it according to its encoding.  In general, you might consider trying to avoid decoding it at all if possible, but if it must be decoded, you must tell the Python decoder how it has been encoded:

```
print(lib.getMessage().decode('utf-8'))
```

for instance.  (Go itself uses utf-8 encoding, but other C items might not use any sensible encoding.)